# Confusion regarding the term 'mount' in Linux

Tags: linux, mount, terminology

I am reading the man page of [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) and [clone](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html).

I understand that mount is used to add a directory hierarchy to a mount point (a directory).

In clone's man page, under the CLONE_NEWNS section, they refer to mounts as the file hierarchy as seen by a process.

My question is that, is the term 'mount' being used to refer to the individual directories in the directory hierarchy seen by a process, and 'mount points' used to refer to the directories where file systems can be mounted ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Id express it like this:

- "mount points": locations in the file hierarchy where file systems have been mounted to
- "mounts": the set of mounted file systems / the set of locations in the file hierarchy where file systems have been mounted to
- "to mount": the action of mounting a file system into the file hierarchy

The view of a process to the file hierarchy does see the mounts insofar as it sees the file hierarchy. This includes those parts where file systems have been mounted into that hierarchy.

Comment: So you're saying : mount points = mounts (both are explained as: locations in the file hierarchy where file systems have been mounted to) ?

Comment: No, that is _not_ what I wrote. Note the "the set" in the second bullet. For me this makes a difference, though indeed only a subtle. Maybe it would be better to label that bullet "_the_ mounts"...

Comment: So 1 mount = 1 mount point && mounts = set of all mount points ?

Comment: Hm, I'd say "_a_ mount" is not so much "a mount point", but "a file system that is mounted" into the file hierarchy. I'd agree to the second statement.

Comment: I asked a related question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/22887514/682869). Could you please answer if you have the time, thanks !

Comment: nice circular definitions. This answer can use some major changes.